# Unexpected "null" token field when using jquery token input - how do I get rid of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, ruby-on-rails-3.1, jquery-tokeninput

I followed this screencast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields?view=asciicast

As one of the steps, I added the prepopulate option as suggested and got the edit form working nicely. This is the javascript, written in coffeescript since I'm using Rails 3.1:

```
  $("#location_token_field").tokenInput "/person/locations.json", {
    crossDomain: false,
    prePopulate: $(this).data("pre"),
    theme: "facebook",
    preventDuplicates: true
  }
```

This is all and well except that **now, in the #new action, the token input field always starts out with "null" there.**

The following is the form part in question:

```
    <div id="location_area">
        <%= link_to image_tag("location_icon2.png", :size=>"35x35"), "javascript:void(0)", id: "location_icon", class: "blank_button" %>
        <div id="location_field">
            <%= f.text_field :location_tokens, id: "location_token_field", placeholder: "Where?", 
                "data-pre" => memory.locations.map(&:attributes).to_json %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any ideas why this is happening / how I can solve this? I would like to keep prepopulate so the edit form is populated appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Just from eying your JavaScript, it looks like you're missing some parentheses:

Try:

```
 $("#location_token_field").tokenInput("/person/locations.json", {
    crossDomain: false,
    prePopulate: $(this).data("pre"),
    theme: "facebook",
    preventDuplicates: true
  });
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this isn't the problem. I tried it and I still get the issue. In any case, I was writing in CoffeeScript, which generates JS equivalent to what you wrote.